# Google Charts API - Dashboard: use calculated columns in a table

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a simple display panel shows Google and I want to add a calculated column in my DataView using SetColumn as shown in this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>
  Google Visualization API Sample
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['controls']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function drawVisualization() {
    // Prepare the data
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Donuts eaten'],
      ['Michael' , 'Male', 12, 5],
      ['Elisa', 'Female', 20, 7],
      ['Robert', 'Male', 7, 3],
      ['John', 'Male', 54, 2],
      ['Jessica', 'Female', 22, 6],
      ['Aaron', 'Male', 3, 1],
      ['Margareth', 'Female', 42, 8],
      ['Miranda', 'Female', 33, 6]
    ]);
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0,1,2,3,1,{
                       calc: mas,
                       type: 'number',
                       label: 'x10',
    }])
      function mas(view2,row) {
          var a = view2.getValue(row,2)*10;
          return a;
      }
    // Define a slider control for the Age column.
    var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
      'containerId': 'control1',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Age',
      'ui': {'labelStacking': 'vertical'}
      }
    });

    // Define a category picker control for the Gender column
    var categoryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
      'containerId': 'control2',
      'options': {
        'filterColumnLabel': 'Gender',
        'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
          'allowTyping': false,
          'allowMultiple': false
        }
      }
    });

    // Define a Pie chart
    var pie = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'PieChart',
      'containerId': 'chart1',
      'options': {
        'width': 300,
        'height': 300,
        'legend': 'none',
        'title': 'Donuts eaten per person',
        'chartArea': {'left': 15, 'top': 15, 'right': 0, 'bottom': 0},
        'pieSliceText': 'label'
      },
      // Instruct the piechart to use colums 0 (Name) and 3 (Donuts Eaten)
      // from the 'data' DataTable.
      'view': {'columns': [0, 3]}
    });

    // Define a table
    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'Table',
      'containerId': 'chart2',
      'options': {
        'width': '300px'
      }
    });

    // Create a dashboard
    new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
        // Establish bindings, declaring the both the slider and the category
        // picker will drive both charts.
        bind([slider, categoryPicker], [pie, table]).
        // Draw the entire dashboard.
        draw(view);
  }


  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
 <div id="dashboard">
  <table>
    <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
      <td style='width: 300px; font-size: 0.9em;'>
        <div id="control1"></div>
        <div id="control2"></div>
        <div id="control3"></div>
      </td>
      <td style='width: 600px'>
        <div style="float: left;" id="chart1"></div>
        <div style="float: left;" id="chart2"></div>
        <div style="float: left;" id="chart3"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

this code is based on another's in "Google Code Playground" and can be tested on the spot.
I am stucked with a problem, when I put setColumn(0,1,2,3,1, "the Calculated column") to allow the table show me these columns, the calculated column is not shown in the table, neither can be used in the PieChart to declare which columns are relevant for the chart.
How I can show a calculated column and use it in a dashboard?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I use your code and just create a table, it displays properly. When I add it to the dashboard code, it doesn't display properly, and despite the view having 5 columns, the chart and table based on that view give an error if I try to pick more than 4. Which is incredibly odd. I cannot debug it despite my best attempts. I would try fiddling with the dashboard, recreating it one component at a time to see where it breaks...

Comment: I can run this code as is (in a dashboard) just fine in Chrome and Firefox.  Does this still cause a problem for folks, or did the recent update fix a bug.  It used to be that dashboards were redundantly serialized and deserialized, which I can imagine causing problems here.